# How can we add inputs in a loop and then further print these inputs in other nested loop?

Tags: python, loops, user-input, calculator, nested-loops

I'm stuck on a problem relates to python. I just clarify it in simple words. How can we start a loop based on user input?
For instance, let's say I want to ask the user to "Enter the total number of subjects" and store this value in a variable and do some type of conversions. Let's say the user enters the value is 6 "Total of Number of subjects = 6". Then initialization of for Loop I wants to print " Enter name of subject 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6" etc. whatever user requirement on each line.  Where a user enters the names of all 6 subjects.

Now, at the next stage, I want to print "Enter marks for subject Phy, Chem" etc. Here I want to start another loop i.e nested loop.

The program is on the aggregate calculator where the user input his total num of subjects and then based on user input I have to ask.

```
Enter subject 1 name: 
Enter subject 2 name:
......
```

And so on based on user input it will increment...
After that, I will ask Marks of each subject that the user have input like physics, English etc.

```
Enter Marks of physics:
Enter marks of computer:
..
...
```

And so on based on user subjects input data...

After that, I will code in such a way that find average and aggregate etc.

Let's look at this example

```
Enter total subjects: 3      #user input
Enter the name of subject 1: English.   #user input
Enter the name of subject 2:  Computer Science. #user input
Enter the name of subject 3: Data Science.   # user input

Enter marks of English:- 56
Enter Marks of Computer Science:- 45
Enter marks of Data Science:- 66
```

And then the calculations process started but I am stuck on upper processes...

But how can I do it????

Comment: Add some code - yours or some pseudocode or Something and I would be more than glad to help. :)

Comment: When the user enters subject names, put them as keys in a dictionary. Then loop through the dictionary, ask for the marks, and use that as the dictionary value.

Comment: @Barmar Why did you comment your answer?

Comment: @Cfomodz I don't think that that can really be counted as an answer, there really is only some kind of generic pseudocode and it is just a concept, however such a concept may help programmers to understand how to write code, give them an idea how to solve it, it is not specific but guiding

Comment: @Cfomodz That's not an answer, it's advice on a general approach. I'm not going to do their homework for them.

Comment: @Barmar Fair enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Number_of_subjects = int(input("Enter total subjects? "))
Subjects = []
for i in range(Number_of_subjects):
    Subjects.append(input(f"Enter the name of subject {i+1}: "))

Marks = []
for x in Subjects:
    Marks.append(float(input(f"Enter marks of {x}: ")))


print (f"Average marks is {sum(Marks) / len(Marks)}")
```

You can use the list of results in "Marks" to do further calculations like Average shown here

Comment: just so You know (You don't have to follow it but it is how Python formatting was intended or sth) there is PEP 8 which states that variable and function names should be `snake_case` and NOT `CapitalCase`

Comment: @Matiiss true - I definitely feel the pain though switching between languages all day. I have many a python program on my crontab that I wrote entirely (or at least got 50%+ through) in camelCase before recognizing I probably shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what problem you have but if its just the code then I can help with that.

```
total = int(input("Enter total number of subjects: "))

subjects = []
for i in range(total):
    subject = input(f"Enter subject {i} name: ")
    subjects.append(subject)

total_mark_sum = 0
marks = []
for i in range(len(subjects)):
    mark = int(input(f"Enter Marks of {subjects[i]}:"))
    marks.append(mark)
    total_mark_sum += mark
print("average=", total_mark_sum/len(subjects))
```

This is really simple and you can us things like dictionary and classes but right now the indexes of subjects and marks match.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an appropriate use of classes.

We will create a Class for subjects:

`class Subject:`

and then define an init:

```
def __init__(self, name, score = 0):
    self.name = name
    self.score = score
```

create an object for each subject upon user input and add it to a list of `Subject` objects

```
list_of_subjects = []
for i in range (total_number_of_subjects):
    subject = Subject(input(f"Enter the name of subject {i+1}: "))
    list_of_subjects.append(subject)
```

Then we can ask them for each `Subject`'s score:

```
for subject in list_of_subjects:
    subject.score = int(input("Enter marks of " + subject.name))
```

Comment: first of it is `class` NOT `Class`, second, add attribute `self.score = score` to the `__init__` method of that class, third, something like this could be used instead, otherwise You are just appending a string to that list: `list_of_subjects.append(Subject(input(f'Enter the name of subject {i + 1}')))` (could also split the input but the point is that You need to create an instance and then add the inputed value to it and then append the INSTANCE to the list)

Comment: @Matiiss frankly this answer was bad and your comments were justified. I did make too many thoughtless mistakes in my answer and thank you for noticing them so that I could edit correcting them and provide a better answer to the original poster.